# Writing latest data without using timestamp

Tags: database, concurrency, cassandra, transactions, locking

I want to write the latest record to db with a specific key. It would be easy if I had a time stamp with the record. But I have sequence number of record instead of time stamp.

Furthermore , the sequence numbers are reset to 0  after reaching a large value( 2^16 ). The sequence number can however be reset anytime even if it doesn't reach 2^16.

I have an option of appending all records and reading the one with largest sequence number. But it will cause problems after a reset(since reset can occur any moment).

The other option is to use Lightweight transactions but I'm not sure if it will guarantee concurrency. Also performance might be affected greatly.

How can I go about doing this. I am using Cassandra DB.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest value, its usually done by keeping log of events and reading first record in it. You can always generate a new timestamp (or timeuuid) when you insert it. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE record (
  id text,
  bucket text,
  created timeuuid,
  info blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id, bucket), created)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC)
```

Then `SELECT * FROM record WHERE id = 'user1' AND bucket = '2017-09-10' LIMIT 1;` where bucket is "today" to prevent partitions getting too large. You have 10k writes per ms per host with timeuuid before you have to worry about collisions.

If you have a  linearizable consistency requirement then you will need to use paxos (lightweight transactions, which will guarantee it if used appropriately) or an external locking system like zookeeper. In a distributed system that kind of thing is more complex and you will never get the same throughput you will as normal writes.